# Reading SNMP Object index of type IPAddress

Tags: parsing, snmp, oid, mib

In a simple SNMP table like `mib-2.interfaces.ifTable`, `ifIndex` is the index for the table, so you read `ifIndex`.1 (i.e. read value from direct child nodes of `ifIndex`) to get the index for the first row of the table.  Simple enough.

But it's not as obvious with something like `mib-2.ip.ipRouteTable`.  In that case `ipRouteIfIndex` is the index column.  It's defined as INTEGER just like `ifIndex` was.  However, you can't read the direct child nodes (i.e. `ifIndex`.0 is a direct child), but instead need to read `ifIndex.0.0.0.0` to get to the value.  So how does one know how to find the value when it's not a direct child of the index column?

There is some concept that I'm not understanding. (Probably having to do with the fact that SNMP objects are delimited by . but so are IP addresses, and I can't tell how to recognize the difference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you have a table with multiple indices in this particular case.

The fact is that you cannot directly read the table entries with `snmp-get` service, since the index is dynamic (and, as a consequence, the OID address). But you can discover the values with `snmp-get-next` (v1) and `snmp-get-bulk` (v2) services.

For example, you can read the indices (and store them for querying table items later) or directly read the items of the table :

- you ask  `snmp-get-next` for *IP-MIB::ipAdEntNetMask*
- the reply will be *IP-MIB::ipAdEntNetMask.172.16.38.42 IPV4 255.255.0.0*
- (So: first index is 172.16.38.42 in that case!)
- you iterate and ask next value after *IP-MIB::ipAdEntNetMask.172.16.38.42*
- the reply will be *IP-MIB::ipAdEntNetMask.172.16.11.43 IPV4 255.255.0.0*
- etc.. until there is no other value, or the value is not on the same tree

The service `snmp-get-bulk` will enable you to query N values directly in this way.

Have a look at *Net-Snmp's* `snmptable` that does good job with tables : http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/TUT:snmptable